How to stop "Allow For One Month" in macOS 15 Sequoia - especially when replayd ScreenCaptureApprovals.plist is missing?
I'm having a particularly strange problem where while, yes, I know everyone is upset about this ridiulous "Allow For One Month" prompt:

My system seems to not remember the settings at all for even five minutes. I can set this, reboot the system and it's right back at it.
After some investigation, it appears that the file where this data is kept is missing on my system:
~/Library/Group\ Containers/group.com.apple.replayd/ScreenCaptureApprovals.plist

Has anyone else seen this? Any "proper" workarounds vs brute forcing creation of this plist?

It's been mentioned that this can be manipulated handily via this blog:

So I attempted to do this for a few tools:
$ defaults write \
  ~/Library/Group\ Containers/group.com.apple.replayd/ScreenCaptureApprovals.plist \
  "/Applications/Setapp/CleanShot X.app/Contents/MacOS/CleanShot X Setapp" \
  -date "3024-09-21 12:40:36 +0000"

$ defaults write \
  ~/Library/Group\ Containers/group.com.apple.replayd/ScreenCaptureApprovals.plist \
  "/Applications/Zight.app/Contents/MacOS/Zight" \
  -date "3024-09-21 12:40:36 +0000"

$ defaults write \
  ~/Library/Group\ Containers/group.com.apple.replayd/ScreenCaptureApprovals.plist \
  "/Applications/DisplayLink\ Manager.app/Contents/MacOS/DisplayLinkUserAgent" \
  -date "3024-09-21 12:40:36 +0000"


And they all appear to show up after this:
$ defaults read ~/Library/Group\ Containers/group.com.apple.replayd/ScreenCaptureApprovals.plist 

{
    "/Applications/DisplayLink\\\\ Manager.app/Contents/MacOS/DisplayLinkUserAgent" = "3024-09-21 12:40:36 +0000";
    "/Applications/Setapp/CleanShot X.app/Contents/MacOS/CleanShot X Setapp" = "3024-09-21 12:40:36 +0000";
    "/Applications/Zight.app/Contents/MacOS/Zight" = "3024-09-21 12:40:36 +0000";
}

But I'm not 100% convinced this is the right approach yet since it clearly appears my replayd config is broken, so I'll come back to this answer to further offer some reports if this works in perpetuity or not.

base on the solution provided by @ylluminate, it can be updated all items via
$ defaults read ~/Library/Group\ Containers/group.com.apple.replayd/ScreenCaptureApprovals.plist |
  sed -nr 's|^\s*"([^"]+)".*$|\1|p' |
  while read -r _name; do
    defaults write ~/Library/Group\ Containers/group.com.apple.replayd/ScreenCaptureApprovals.plist \
             "${_name}" -date "3024-01-01 00:00:00 +0000";
  done

verified:
# original
$ defaults read ~/Library/Group\ Containers/group.com.apple.replayd/ScreenCaptureApprovals.plist
{
    "/Applications/Bob.app/Contents/MacOS/Bob" = "2024-09-19 22:33:43 +0000";
    "/Applications/GIF Brewery 3.app/Contents/MacOS/GIF Brewery 3" = "2024-09-21 10:34:48 +0000";
    "/Applications/Snipaste.app/Contents/MacOS/Snipaste" = "2024-10-22 07:04:02 +0000";
    "/Applications/zoom.us.app/Contents/MacOS/zoom.us" = "2024-10-15 06:12:23 +0000";
}

# update
$ defaults read ~/Library/Group\ Containers/group.com.apple.replayd/ScreenCaptureApprovals.plist |
  sed -nr 's|^\s*"([^"]+)".*$|\1|p' |
  while read -r _name; do
    defaults write ~/Library/Group\ Containers/group.com.apple.replayd/ScreenCaptureApprovals.plist \
             "${_name}" -date "3024-01-01 00:00:00 +0000";
  done


# verify
defaults read ~/Library/Group\ Containers/group.com.apple.replayd/ScreenCaptureApprovals.plist
{
    "/Applications/Bob.app/Contents/MacOS/Bob" = "3024-01-01 00:00:00 +0000";
    "/Applications/GIF Brewery 3.app/Contents/MacOS/GIF Brewery 3" = "3024-01-01 00:00:00 +0000";
    "/Applications/Snipaste.app/Contents/MacOS/Snipaste" = "3024-01-01 00:00:00 +0000";
    "/Applications/zoom.us.app/Contents/MacOS/zoom.us" = "3024-01-01 00:00:00 +0000";
}


I wrote a script to help control these annoying nags. It's on GitHub at luckman212/screencapture-nag-remover
When run without arguments, it iterates over any entries contained in the ~/Library/Group Containers/group.com.apple.replayd/ScreenCaptureApprovals.plist and sets their nag date to 100 years in the future. It can also add arbitrary apps to the list by supplying args in the form of -a <path> (-a <bundle_id> on 15.1).
Examples
# for macOS 15.0
screencapture-nag-remover.sh -a "/Applications/CleanShot X.app/Contents/MacOS/CleanShot X"

# for macOS 15.1
screencapture-nag-remover.sh -a cc.ffitch.shottr

This may help the OP with his issue where the apps or the plist itself are not being set correctly. If the plist does not exist, the program will create it.
Other features
Some other features exist (run with -h to see all options):

can generate a Configuration Profile (.mobileconfig) that permanently blocks nags on MDM-joined machines running 15.1 or higher
optionally install a LaunchAgent that runs periodically to keep your MRU dates current to prevent the nags from recurring, even with infrequently-used apps (a remove function is included as well)


How would that work if the file doesn't exist, which is what the original question states?

@Ezekiel if the plist does not exist, the script will create it. I don't have the problem tbat the OP is experiencing, so I can't say for sure if it will solve it, but it is worth trying.

Credit to Marslo.  This uses xargs instead of while.
#!/bin/bash

SCA=~/Library/Group\ Containers/group.com.apple.replayd/ScreenCaptureApprovals.plist

defaults read "$SCA" | sed -nre 's/.*"(.*)" = ".*".*/\1/p' | \
  xargs -I {} defaults write "$SCA" "{}" "9999-01-01 00:00:00 +0000"

# Verify
defaults read "$SCA"


